# No poses returned by estimatePoses in BlazePose TFJS pose detection

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js, mediapipe, pose-detection

Trying to get [BlazePose TFJS](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/05/high-fidelity-pose-tracking-with-mediapipe-blazepose-and-tfjs.html) working in Angular 12.  I have an empty project and have installed the requires packages (I think).  Package.json looks like this:

```html
{
  "name": "posetrackingtest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@mediapipe/pose": "^0.3.1621277220",
    "@tensorflow-models/pose-detection": "^0.0.3",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.7.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^3.7.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

I have a single component with the following HTML:

```html
<video
    #videoplayer
    id="videoplayer"
    autoplay>
</video>
```

My typescript code for the component is:

```html
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
import * as poseDetection from '@tensorflow-models/pose-detection';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pose',
  templateUrl: './pose.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pose.component.css']
})
export class PoseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild("videoplayer", { static: false }) videoplayer: ElementRef;

  public detector: any;
  public poses: any;
  public error: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}


  ngAfterViewInit () : void{
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {

    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true
        });
        if (stream) {
          console.log(stream);
          this.videoplayer.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;

          console.log(this.videoplayer.nativeElement);

          console.log("About to load detector");
          let detectorConfig = {
            runtime: 'tfjs',
            enableSmoothing: true,
            modelType: 'full'
          };
          this.detector = await poseDetection.createDetector(poseDetection.SupportedModels.BlazePose, detectorConfig);
          console.log(this.detector);
          console.log("Detector loaded");

          let poses = await this.detector.estimatePoses(this.videoplayer.nativeElement);

          console.log(poses);

          this.error = null;
        } else {
          this.error = "You have no output video device";
        }
      } catch (e) {
        this.error = e;
      }
    }

  }


}
```

I don't get any errors, can see myself via the webcam on the HTML page when I execute it, but the output of `console.log(poses);` is just an empty list `[]`.  i.e. no pose data.

Also, how do I get the `let poses = await this.detector.estimatePoses(this.videoplayer.nativeElement);` line to execute constantly?  Does the `this.poses` variable get updated constantly or do I need to iterate somehow?

What am I doing wrong please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a relatively similar issue(null Blazepose output, although I was using pure javascript). To fix this issue I setup my camera following what google did in their camera.js file(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/pose-detection/demos/live_video/src/camera.js).

```
const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];

if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      throw new Error(
          'Browser API navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not available');
    }
    const videoConfig = {
      'audio': false,
      'video': {
        facingMode: 'user',
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        frameRate: {
          ideal: 60,
        }
      }
    };

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConfig);

    videoElement.srcObject = stream;

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      videoElement.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        resolve(videoElement);
      };
    });

    videoElement.play();
    resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(canvasElement)

    const videoWidth = videoElement.videoWidth;
    const videoHeight = videoElement.videoHeight;
    // Must set below two lines, otherwise video element doesn't show.
    videoElement.width = videoWidth;
    videoElement.height = videoHeight;
    
}
```

To answer the part about getting the line to execute constantly, I used requestAnimationFrame

```
async function updateVideo(){
    const poses = await detector.estimatePoses(videoElement,    estimationConfig, timestamp);
    await updateScreen(poses)
    //console.log(poses)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateVideo);
}
```

Then we can start this loop once the video has loaded

```
videoElement.onloadeddata = async function() {
        updateVideo()
}
```

This can also be done using setInterval, however request animation frame is preferable as it will not cause a backlog if you end up falling behind the current frame, it will skip ahead to the current frame.

Comment: Thanks that's great.  I'll check this approach out.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! The missing link for me were setting videoElement.width = videoWidth and videoElement.height = videoHeight.